# How to cut or remove part of video, using videoJS?

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I need to create a simple video editor, in which users can select and remove parts of the videos. How can i achieve this using videoJS? For the server side i will use ffmpeg, so i only need to resolve this from the frontend now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to worry about videojs for this, as it's a wrapper around the HTML5 `<video>` element that helps with playback controls, etc.  You can simply query the `<video>` element itself for the positions where the user has presumably selected an in/out point.  Create a list of these in/out points if there is more than one, and then allow the user to submit this cut-list to the server via an AJAX call.  Do your editing on the server-side, then pass back a link to the view video via the response to the AJAX call.  Then set the `<src>` of the `<video>` element to the new edited video.

Comment: Thanks! But dont you think this wont be user-friendly? I just need to check how much time it takes to do this and "refresh" the player..

Comment: You could have some type of user feedback animation while the video processing is happening on the server, so I don't see why this wouldn't be user-friendly.  All the "refreshing" is happening through the AJAX calls, so it's not like the user would have to manually refresh the page.  They would just need to "submit" their changes to the video, i.e., their cut-list.

Comment: Yeah sure, but i was thinking of doing a editor that  dont even have to send ajax request, and the "edition" is automatically without waiting. Anyways, will try this and wait for other options. Thanks for your time!

Comment: For something like that you're probably going to have to control playback yourself, and buffering, etc., by the browser could get in your way since MPEG-4 is a LONG-GOP format and doesn't lend itself well to actual frame-by-frame editing without first fully decoding the video stream.  You're talking about doing something a lot lower-level than anything videojs would give you access to.  You could maybe try using a `<canvas>` element that pulled from a hidden `<video>` element for its 2D texture, and use `requestAnimationFrame()` to update playback.